# Authorization in microservices - list of rows user can access

Tags: authorization, microservices

We are splitting our monolith solution into microservices. One of the microservices will be authorization one which is responsible to determine whether user can access particular entities.

In our system we allow to define access to projects to given users according to various criteria:

- user is manager of a project,
- user is directly assigned to project,
- user is assigned to a project via a presence in a team,
- etc.

There are rules which determine whether user can or can not see a project.

Authorization microservice will be responsible to determine whether user can access a project. For the sake of project search (via name) and displaying accessible projects it should be also able to return list of all accessible projects for a user.

The problem is that this list may be huge (even thousands of projects seems to be a problem). So we cannot afford to build a query in other microservices like this:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE id IN ({list-of-accessible-projects-from-microservice})
```

Because such query might not be accepted by RDBMS due to its length. Also I am worried of performance (large list in `IN` clause might slow it down). I will benchmark it, but I am curious of another approaches how can I accomplish this using standalone authorization microservice. Or using another approach (e.g. virtual table per user with list of projectIds which I can JOIN to query).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue is essentially that the number of projects a User might have access to is unbounded - it can (and likely will) grow forever.  If that's right, your concerns about performance are absolutely correct.

This seems like a great opportunity to have the Authorization service publish a `UserProjectAccessChanged` integration event with details about the `UserID`(s), `TeamID`(s), and `ProjectID`(s) affected.  Your `ManageProjects` service should subscribe to this event and keep a local persisted copy of the Users and their level of Access for each project.  The local table(s) can be constructed in such a way that not only will queries be fast, but you'll only need to hit a single service to get your answers (either a list of Projects by User or Users by Project).

Different microservices keeping their own copy of related data can be a very powerful tool and was conceived exactly to help solve issues like this.  [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/data-considerations) has some good insights that might be relevant for you.